# Alternatives to Mcrypt for encryption / decryption in PHP?

Tags: php, drupal, encryption, mcrypt

I'm giving some code for a Drupal module that needs to do encryption and decryption. I dont think I can assume that the Mcrypt module is installed on the Drupal system. What can i use as an alternative encryption mechanism?

This isnt for financial stuff, so i dont need sophisticated cryptology, but better is beter...

Comment: Can you assume that php is installed at all? If no - then why don't select another programming language then?

Comment: that was a wierd sarcastic comment

Comment: @Frank D: it was. But that is how "software requirements" work. Use whatever you want and need to create your code (and make it perfect, performant and readable) and then specify all the dependencies in a requirements readme part. This is true for every program, don't try to avoid it.

Comment: i'm agreeing with you, but i'm in the position to _change_ how i do things depending on the wideness of the platform - and the latter is more important to me. hope you see my perspective

Comment: @Frank D: sure I see, but my opinion is to use mcrypt and don't look at some php-based clone.

Comment: Wordpress doesn't even use curl.  Instead, they bundle a PHP-based substitute.  I think that says a lot about what you have to do if you're looking for really wide distribution for PHP code.  In some contexts, you can afford to require your users to recompile PHP to include optional libraries; in others, you'll just lose those users.

Comment: There has been serious discussion about removing mcrypt from PHP 7 - the underlying third-party library has essentially been abandoned. While mcrypt will likely be "in" for PHP 7, there is a clear long-term need for a cryptographically-secure alternative.

Comment: Not that this is of any help when you don't control the server, but if you look for a more up to date alternative for mcrypt, check out Sodium: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about using your database? MySQL has AES and DES encryption and decryption functions. You could then use a "fake" query to get your string:

```
select id, aes_encrypt('My secret text', 'the key string') 
from permissions 
limit 1
```

(MySQL returns an empty set if you don't have at least one field from the table.)

Decryption works the same way. It's 128-bit AES, which is not too bad, cryptographically, and if you can't even be sure about MCrypt, I doubt you will be recompiling MySQL to get 256-bit AES.

Comment: very iunteresting approach... food for thought!

Comment: More important than the keysize is what blockcipher mode it is using? Do you know that by any chance.

Comment: clever. In my version of MySQL, `SELECT aes_encrypt('My secret text', 'the key string');` works.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods of encrypting PHP codes, using a key to encrypt/decrypt codes makes it more secure as an alternate to MCrypt.

One way is creating a function that may require a key to complete an encryption or decryption.
PHP has its built-in functions like `gzdeflate()` or `gzinflate()`, another is using `base64_encode()`/`base64_decode()` and `str_rot13()` functions.

But I don't think using [PHP Encoder](http://adromil.myxednotes.com) would work.

Answer (score 1):

The [Encryption module](http://drupal.org/project/encrypt) module includes a basic encryption method by default, which it describes as "A simple mathematical encryption method that does not require any PHP extensions."

Answer (score 1):

based on Leon's answer, [PHP Encoder](http://adromil.myxednotes.com) is using MCrypt module that may not work on Drupal. Another way is is to use IonCube Encoder.

If you want a more strict function, you may also try to use `hash()` and `md5()` function to create your key and require it on you encrypting function with the returns of `gzdeflate()`/`gzinflate()` functions as what [Leon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733846/leon-alexis-cardinal)'s suggestion.